# Python: How to ensure that a file gets deleted when the program finishes?

Tags: python-3.x, temp

I have several files that absolutely have to be deleted when the program finishes. I don't really want to use `tempfile.TemporaryFile` because the files have to be passed around quite a bit, and be used for command output redirection in `os.system()` calls. So I would use `tempfile.mkstemp`, but these don't get deleted automatically. I thought about wrapping my main method in a try-finally like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    finally:
        os.remove(tempfile)
```

but that looks rather questionable. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not use a temporary directory instead?

Comment: on that route, there's `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir: ...` since python3.2

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that this deletes the files as well. That's what you get for only scanning the documentation:) Thank you!

Comment: Using a `try..finally` block to surround your main process is as far as you can go in guaranteeing that a clean up procedure is called on exit (to delete all temporary files for example). That still doesn't mean it will _absolutely_ get called (a user can hard-kill your process, Python might segfault, the PSU on the computer might die...) but it will in normal state of operation. Also, if you want to remove those files due to security concerns, don't store the files in the first place - create a ramdisk or a similar virtual FS first and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

My question has been answered by the comments above, but I've found another neat solution that I'll just leave here for future reference: [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/atexit.html)